# What could have changed email headers?

Tags: email

I'm sending email programmatically with the following headers:

```
From: rm-noreply@mycompany.com
Reply-To: rm-noreply@mycompany.com
```

However, recipients sees them differently

```
From: "Some Name" <rm-noreply@mycompany.com>
Reply-To: "Some Name" <rm-noreply@mycompany.com>
```

Has this change been done by: sending SMTP server, some server on a way, receiving server or mail client of a user?

Answer (score 2):

Your code probably invokes a system mail program to send mail. This will usually add the full name.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a cause in my case. I have sent email to myself with "rm-noreply@mycompany.com" in CC, and the CC header has not been expanded. So it must be some other system.

Comment: Could you post `Received:` header of the above mentioned email?